# Running Blender Game Engine in background

Tags: python, game-engine

I'm currently using the blender game engine to simulate robotics.

In order to evolve quickly in my research, I'd like to start simulations running with the Blender Game Engine on a distant cluster, get some feedback in a script ("is there any collision?", for example), use this feedback to modify the model in the script, and iterate...

At the moment, I can start it along with the GUI interface:

> blender model.blend --python start_script.py

Where start_script.py is just:

```
import bpy
bpy.context.scene.game_settings.use_auto_start = True
bpy.ops.view3d.game_start()
```

However, when I try to run it in background:

> blender model.blend --python start_script.py -b

This fails with error:

> wmSubWindowScissorSet 0: doesn't exist
>
> Writing: /tmp/test_ge.crash.txt
>
> Segmentation fault (core dumped)

Any idea how I can avoid this?

Thanks a lot!!

Comment: I do not think the BGE (or any other game engine) is sufficient for such a purpose. --- If you need a physics simulation I suggest to look for Bullet. It is the Physics engine the BGE is using. I'm sure there are (non-game engine) applications that support simulations much better.